# When declaring an event handler within a handler, does the inner handler have access to arguments passed to the outer handler?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, event-handling

I am reviewing some nodejs code and found something that doesn't look correct to me.  It has to do with event handling of a socket.  It seems that a on message handler, that is declared within the on connection handler, uses the socket object that was passed in during the connection event.  Is that variable valid later when the message event occurred?  Here is an outline of the code:

It seems to work, but I'm not sure if it is correct.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    socket.emit('data', databuf)
  }
})
```

Does the socket.emit statement have a valid socket object at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have access to all parent function scopes in child functions. As long as you keep it in the same curly braces you have access. (or if it's a global variable)

Comment: Thank you.  I was concerned that the argument for the io.on callback would be volatile and disappear after the callback returned.  I guess I didn't realize that the arguments were static.

Comment: no problem. It can be easy to think of your functions as "event hanlders", but they really are "functions" that are passed in as an argument to another function that sets up an event handler. Your variables are block scoped within functions so you are all set.